# Establish the convergence or divergence of the series whose nth term is $\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

The series whose nth term is $\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}$, I have to check the convergence or divergence of it.

So $$a_n=\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{2}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$ Hence as $n\to \infty$, $a_n\to 0$ so the series is convergent.

Am I correct?

Comment: it is divergent. compare with [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: How can I show that? Where did my mistake lies? @Mirko

Comment: The most common example for this is $a_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$, which $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ but is a divergent series.

Comment: $a_n \to 0$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition for a series to be convergent.

Comment: I see. So I can prove it by limit comparison test right?

Comment: yes [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
For limit comparison, take $x_n=\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ and $y_n=1/n$.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the limit comparison test with the $n$th harmonic number as suggested by @Mirko
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}\over \frac1n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{  n^2}{n (n+2)}=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac1{1+\frac{2}{n}}=1>0$$
Then both series diverge because it is well know that the [harmonic series diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence).

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges.
Indeed $$\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)} \sim_{\infty} \frac {1}{n}$$ that diverges